# Scrolling - creating thumbnails from images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

Could somebody go over how to modify the [Scrolling Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html) so that it shows one image with others partly showing to the left and right? Just like mobile safari when you go to the page manager...This is key so that the user knows there are more images if they scroll to the right. **Both methods taken from Scrolling project.**

METHOD TO SET UP SCROLLVIEW:

```
ViewDidLoad {

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];

// 1. setup the scrollview for multiple images and add it to the view controller
//
// note: the following can be done in Interface Builder, but we show this in code for clarity
[scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;        // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;

// pagingEnabled property default is NO, if set the scroller will stop or snap at each photo
// if you want free-flowing scroll, don't set this property.
scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;

// load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

[self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
}
```

METHOD TO SET LAYOUT:

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
[scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in my previous app i create image galley view where i put some custom  button on scroll view, so user can see full image on click on that button.

here is code hope it will help you

```
        UIScrollView *Sview = [[UIScrollView alloc] 
                      initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

int row = 0;
int column = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < self.data.getCustomers.count; ++i) {

     customerToEdit = [self.data.getCustomers objectAtIndex:i];


     NSURL* imgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your image url array objects"];

    UIImage* thumb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl]];

    //UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];

    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*100+24, row*80+10, 64, 64);

    [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.tag = i; 

    [Sview addSubview:button];

    if (column == 2) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
    } else {
        column++;
    }

}

[view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1) * 80 + 10)];   
self.view = view; // or u can  [self.view addsubview:Sview];
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to post a screenshot of what this produces? thanks!

Comment: i will give u tomorrow because currently my office is going to close, it display the images in grid-view.